# How to make every domain class, controller and service multi tenant in grails 4?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, multi-tenant

In grails 4 (grails 3+), we have to mark the domain classes with multi tenant trait and also its respective services and controllers.
For eg :

```
class Book implements MultiTenant<Book> {
    String title
}

@CurrentTenant
class BookService {

    @WithoutTenant
    int countBooks() {
        Book.count()
    }
}
```

Is there a configuration for gorm to make everything as multi tenant? My requirement is, based on domain name for eg: abc.com or xyz.com where tenants are abc and xyz i need to switch database but i don't want to go on to annotate each domain class and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a configuration for gorm to make everything as multi tenant?

No.

You have options like you could build an AST transformation that would do such a thing, but no feature like that exists in the framework itself.

Comment: marking every single thing as multitenant is giving me issues like no session bound. So what i am trying to do is create multiple datasources, get separate connection of datasource based on domain name. Basically i am trying to write manual code for connecting datasource. Is such thing possible? Since AbstractRoutingDataSource is not supported anymore i am trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: "marking every single thing as multitenant is giving me issues like no session bound. " - There has to be more to it than that.  Marking every domain class as multitenant and marking a service as multitenant is not problematic by itself.